# Inserting data in Microsoft Dynamics C5 from C#

Tags: c#

I need to transfer some data from our CRM system into the [Microsoft Dynamics C5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_C5) accountance system.

Is this possible? Writing directly in a SQL database and such hacks will be fine for me as well.

Comment: Hmmm. For that, I think you'll have to write the code for exporting the files to a particular folder using CRM. Then you'll have to figure out a way to import it back to C5 using code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised no one had this need.

Anyway after talking to a consultant I found out that there are two ways to solve it.

1. Install C5 on a SQL server you manage and manipulate the data directly.
2. Default C5 install with a Native DB and buy the C5 ODBC module that makes it
   possible  to manipulate the data through ODBC.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting data directly to a Dynamics C5 SQL database - will give you problems if you don't remember to use a correct LXBENUMMER/ROWNUMBER.
You have to use a unique number for each row. Rownumbers are managed by the table XALSEQ.
Remember that empty strings must contain a CHAR(2).

Otherwise you could look at XU4N - that will give you a .NET entry to the Dynamics C5 application (not the data-layer).
www.dns-it.dk/xu4n

Regards
Erling Damsgaard

Comment: Tak for svaret, kontakter jer hvis det bliver aktuelt at integrere igen.. ikke noget jeg længere ønsker at rode med :)

Answer (score 0):

You can export data from CRM system in an excel file. Then import the same Excel file into your C5 system.

Comment: Yes I have figured this much, but we would like it to happen on the fly

Answer (score 0):

There is the option of buying solutions from vendors as well (yes I'm working for one, just for the record...so I might fanzy our product over others).

The concept we have is a "designer" where you create a mapping from c5 to "whatever", at the moment we have a mapping towards C# and other C5 versions, the concept will probably be expanded to Ax and interfacing to other programming languages.

We run a C5 that responds to our "mappings", with a pinch of magic ;) and yes ofcourse there is a cost at doing this but as we tell all our customers...why replicate business logic.

So in the end...you can insert data into C5 without running straight to the database...which can be very bad if people have triggers or other stuff happening when they insert data into C5.